# Add accept rate to profile page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accept-rate

I know this request has been made several times, but I would like to highlight some issues with the current system as it stands.

At the moment, the accept rate is not displayed on a user's profile and numerous requests for its display as well as its removal has been suggested. These questions date back quite a few years and nothing has really been done since then.

I would like to highlight while accept rate is not visible on the profile page, it is visible when browsing one's profile through the Stack Remote mobile application. I do understand that it is third party but it does not change the fact that the Stack Exchange API provides enough information for it to calculate acceptance rate.

Based on this, I would recommend that the accept rate be displayed on the profile page with a possible preference to make it private (possibly even completely private with no way to make it public). A publicly displayed accept rate has already been heavily disputed to the point of removal but nothing has been said about a private one. Its always nice to have some sort of reference as to should one accept more answers or not.

I do not know the full history and exact status of the accept rate functionality as it currently stands so I apologize if this question seems out of place or out of time.

**Edit:**
It seems I've haven't made it clear enough that I am proposing a system where accept rates are private and serve as a personal indicator rather than a public display. From how looks at the moment, people strongly oppose this feature. Just making my point clearer for the sake of it and sorry for any misconceptions I may have caused.

**Edit 2:**
A further proposal goes such that not only do you get a private accept rate displayed somewhere on your profile, warnings or notices are issued regarding the importance of accepting an answered are given when your accept rate is too low (maybe only when rate == 0). This allows people new to the system to be able to quickly understand how it works and have a means of "tracking their progress".

Comment: Accept rates are not visible **anywhere**. Why should they be displayed on the profile page? What's the compelling argument for displaying them **at all**?

Comment: As for a bit of history - the metric was proving to be more of a bother than of use (people used it as a tool to be rude to those will low rates).

Comment: @Oded A privately displayed acceptance rate can serve as a reminder to people who don't accept enough answers. And the general behavior seems somewhat inconsistent (web based vs mobile apps) with most mobile apps that utilize the Stack Exchange API (which tend to all privately display accept rates).

Comment: Accept rate is a pointless metric. The sooner we forget about it, the better.

Comment: Again, you are talking about **third party** apps that display this information. I fail to see why that means **we** should use a metric we found to be harmful - and people with low accept rates will not change their behavior based on a number on their profile page.

Comment: @Oded "people with low accept rates will not change their behavior based on a number on their profile page." That's an assumption... Personally after looking at my own accept rates, I went to review each of my questions to see if I could accept anything. I believe if it was displayed privately, it can turn into something quite useful... But if the rest of the community disagrees, I'll shut up.

Comment: In regards to the API - it still reports the value as removing it would be a breaking change.

Comment: I have asked for a compelling reason - looking after your own accept rate is easy enough without this. You go through your list of questions and look through each one that has no accepted answer - as you know, this is color coded. Having a single number on your profile page doesn't change the need for this exercise when managing  accepts, so... what's the point again?

Comment: @Oded Well... Someone at some point thought it was an useful feature... To be able to see it at glance seems like a nice touch but I suppose you're right... If no one else posts any thing to this discussion should I just delete the question?

Comment: Sure. But the history of the feature showed that it was not that useful after all. So it was removed.

Comment: And no - don't delete it. I am only one (rather biased) dev. The community has not spoken yet and opposing views may come, or good answers may yet show up. Give it some time. Discussion and review is never a bad thing.

Comment: @Oded Okay... I'll give it some time... Hope my rep doesn't drop to zero in the meantime :). Votes are currently -1 and dropping...

Comment: @CPUTerminator - on Meta, that's rather slow... mean it isn't overly controversial.

Comment: Something really unpopular could be at -15 by now

Comment: @RichardTingle Wow... People are brutal here... People on SO suddenly seem... almost... nice.

Comment: The difficulty is that on Stack overflow downvotes mean "this question is bad" here it can mean that **or** we disagree

Comment: @CPUTerminator - probably because [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: just search for `is:question user:me hasaccepted:0`?

Comment: Two important things to remember are; your SO rep is safe; meta is separate and question bans are very hard to get here

Comment: @RichardTingle Quick indicator of whether one should be accepting more answers. Possibly even a notice or prompt associated with a low rate teaching people the importance of accepting answers.

Comment: Possibly a 0% accept rate could generate a message (actually I'd be in favour of that,  in fact put that in your question and I'll +1 it) but beyond that; maybe you ask difficult question (or questions in obscure languages) or just have high standards

Answer (score 6):

The accept rate is a distraction, it is a metric that has a certain amount of value, but by displaying it publicly in the user signature it was elevated far beyond what it actually meant. There are far more important aspect to participation on an SE site that have no convenient numerical value attached to it.

Accept rate is a controversial metric, while the extreme of 0% accept rate is usually agreed to be a sign of a user not understanding the system, or not caring about it, there is not much agreement beyond this. Many users only accept answers if they think they are complete and exhausting, others accept anything that provides them with any amount of additional information. And then there is the suspicion that some users are badgered into accepting an answer even if they are not satisfied.

Making the accept rate public and visible has a well-known drawback, and that is all the comments asking users to improve their accept rate and all the discussions and trouble those lead to. I haven't seen a convincing argument that the value of the public display of the accept rate is worth it.

Comment: I didn't see it linked above so [just for some history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)...